# I have an InDesign file in CC version, but I need it in a CS6 version

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, cs6, creative-cloud

I have an InDesign file in CC version, but I need it in a CS6 version
is there any online converter?

Answer (score 3):

In the **Save As** menu, change the save **Format** in the dropdown menu to **InDesign CS4 or later (IDML)**:

[image]

This should take care of any compatibility issues with earlier versions of Creative Suite.